# Building a 3D IR scanner with USB power

Tags: infrared, camera, 3d

I am trying to build a 3D scanner which can work with USB power. I am using an IR camera and a IR projector. I would like to scan objects up to a distance of 4m (indoor) with minimum 640x480 resolution.

Does anyone know how to project a fixed IR pattern using a projector or IR LEDs. I am trying to design a 3D scanner, finding the IR camera is easy but I am having problem finding a low-power IR projector (or speckle projector). Any other ideas like using only IR LEDs in the design?

Comment: The device you are describing is implemented in a Kinect. The oem was called Primesense. The Kinect has an ir laser emitter with a fixed pattern and a camera. There is an ASIC controlling the two. You may be able to start hacking there.

Comment: The problem is Primesense is not the market hence no ASIC and there are no good supplier for IR projector either (as far as I know). This is the reason I want to try with a constant pattern and processing the IR pics using the software.

Answer (score 2):

You should place a small [gobo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gobo_(lighting)) between the LED and a projective optic (I'd recommend buying a [small 1/3" or 1/4" lens](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/search?Ns=p_PRICE_2%7C0&ci=23731&setNs=p_PRICE_2%7C0&N=3880127305%204288580116&view=Grid&srtclk=sort) to prototype with). The gobo can be purchased or custom-made with a pattern of holes that would either be laser-cut, chemically-etched, or mechanically drilled. The projective optic is the magic -- when focused properly to the face of the gobo plate, it will project the pattern crisply onto surfaces in the scene. Note that the gobo will reduce the light output significantly; you may struggle to get the scene lit brightly enough without a large, clumsy IR LED COB package, which would require a sizable heatsink.

Comment: This is really useful. I will try to prototype it. I am thinking of using [830nm and 60mW IR diode](http://www.wavespectrum-laserdiode.com/sell-779949-830nm-100mw-laser-diode-with-pd.html) like Microsoft Kinect.

Comment: Yeah, I've actually used this technique to do basically what you're talking about -- albeit on a much smaller scale (we did a 2x2 cm gobo plate with a 40x40 grid of points that were laser-etched with a diameter of 50 micron). You may need to use a bigger lens (C-mount or something), but the overall technique should work regardless of the size of the environment.

Comment: Why do we need to use a lens? (Is it needed to increase FOV) BTW Microsoft Kinect does not use any lens for IR projector. Also can we use 2 IR didoes and increase the intensity?

Comment: See the pic of [Kinect IR Projector](http://gmv.cast.uark.edu/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/IR.jpg), there is no lens. It has just a protector.

Comment: There's definitely a lens in the photo you linked to. Without a coherent light source, light rays will emit from the gobo at all angles, which will cause the pattern to lose focus. You can either create a coherent light source (hard), or put a lens in front of the gobo to focus the pattern out into space. This is basic optics you should have learned in your high school physics class. Cameras and projectors work the same way -- just backwards from each other.

Answer (score 1):

If all you need is a pattern of IR 'dots' projected for your IR camera(s), you can take any IR source you want (IR LEDs are cheap), place it in a reflector capsule (like a flashlight or headlight reflector), then drill a pattern of small holes in a metal plate & place the plate in front of your IR source.

This can give you exactly the patrern of your choosing, with clean edges on the 'dots,' and, if your reflector-plate fitments it well sealed, can give 0 'leakage' light escaping to interfere with the contrast for your camera(s).

Comment: Why would you want a reflector?  To get a sharp pattern, you'd need a point source of light, which suggests to me a single LED with everything around it painted black.

Comment: @SimonB Depending on your light source & your reflector, it's often more effective to use a good parabolic reflector, then shield the direct radiation forward from the source (like many vehicle headlamps). While direct+reflected light both hitting the same aperture will always spoil your pattern, blocking direct & allowing reflected (from a well-designed parabolic reflector) can actually give better edge definition & size regularity (due to longer focal distance btwn source and aperture), better pattern regularity (for same reason), and sometimes better utilization of available output.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I will try this approach. For the IR dots pattern what is the best way to "drill the pattern of holes on a metal plate". Can I use laser drilling on a think plastic plate?

Comment: @ky3d if you have access to a laser drill, then I very truly envy you (and yes, it should work great). The only thing is that most plastics are ir transmissive (i.e. plastic is to IR as glass is to visible light); metals are the best light blockers ever. If your laser drill can't handle an aluminum or stainless plate, a 1/16" bit in a drill press should work a treat. ;-)

Comment: No I don't have a laser drill :) most probably I will get it done from outside. I have contacted some laser companies regarding creating a custom pattern. This [google link](http://answers.google.com/answers/threadview/id/93216.html) is also very useful.